# rasa nlu predict the right entity but wrong intent

Tags: rasa

i have a mail intent that use regex :

```
## regex:regex_mail
- .\*@.*

## intent:consultation-dossier2
- [email@gmail.com](regex_mail)
- [cncc@gmail.fr](regex_mail)
- [cncc.leather@planet.tn](regex_mail)
- [contact@cetime.com.tn](regex_mail)
- [ebtgeg@egrg.aege](regex_mail)
```

the problem is that in typing "documentation@gmail.com",nlu recognize the entity "regex_mail" but chose the intent "documentation".

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pvSsCZsqEt8HuSVaZr8x9sIn8LgqnZuu

Comment: That's probably because the word `documentation` isn't present in your intent `consultation-dossier-2`. And I don't think intent prediction is influenced by entity types so you may want to extract the entity by some other way such as using forms.

Comment: @wael BTW, you didn't supply the `documentation' intent examples. It could be usefule to have them to think about what happens

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the way you have trained the bot, "intent classification" will not happen correctly.
If all you want is to "detect" when the user says a valid email address then you can always check whether the *regex_mail* entity got detected or not. And if yes, whether the value is new or not. No need to train intent classification for that.

But if you want to train to classify sentences which has email address, then you can train something like below:

```
## intent:consultation-dossier2
- My email is [email@gmail.com](regex_mail)
- Please mail me at [cncc@gmail.fr](regex_mail)
- Is your address [cncc.leather@planet.tn](regex_mail) correct? or no?
```